# How is it possible to make a multi-index search using Azure Search API?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

How can I made search into multiple index using azure search API?

For example:

```
https://{0}/indexes**('Place','vehicle')**/docs?api-version={1}&search={2}&$count=true".
```

**Is it possible or not?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on my understanding of the search service, it is not possible to do searches spanning multiple indexes using the API. You would need to do searches on each index individually and then merge the results somehow on the client side.